# How to retrieve startup folder location in 64-bit Windows

Tags: vbscript, 64-bit, startup

I have a VB script that adds a program shortcut to the Windows Startup folder.  In my script, I'm able to retrieve the Startup folder location in 32-bit Windows with this:

```
  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  startupFolder = objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
```

but it returns nothing when I try this on 64-bit Windows.  Specifically, I'm testing on 64-bit Vista.  I can't seem to find the appropriate environment variable or syntax for this.  Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me on 64-bit Windows Vista Enterprise and returns `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. Ran the script under both 32-bit and 64-bit script hosts.

Comment: Strange.  I'm not sure why my code doesn't work.  Oh well, your answer below works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try an alternative variant using the [`Shell.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094.aspx) object:

```
Const ssfSTARTUP = &H7

Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set startupFolder = oShell.NameSpace(ssfSTARTUP)

If Not startupFolder Is Nothing Then
  WScript.Echo startupFolder.Self.Path
End If
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: Yeah!  Works on 32 and 64-bit.  Thanks Helen.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works.  This actually reads the registry value where the folder is stored.  I can' imagine why the other method doesn't work in 64-bit.

```
Dim startupFolder As String
startupFolder = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue _
("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders", "Startup", Nothing)
```

Comment: I just realized I had my question tagged as vb and not vbscript.  Your code doesn't work in vbscript...thanks though.   For now, I'll just hardcode the startup location (!!) for 64-bit.